# Single-click-editable bound CheckBox in Xceed DataGridControl

Tags: wpf, checkbox, xceed-datagrid

I've spent the past hour searching for solutions to what should be a simple problem: how to create a single-click-editable bound `CheckBox` in Xceed's community `DataGridControl`.

To be clear: I want a `CheckBox` column where the user may click any `CheckBox`, regardless of what row is selected, and have the view model's `IsSelected` property changing accordingly.

Below is the latest permutation I've tried. This code reads the value from the model, but clicking the `CheckBox` does not call the `IsSelected` setter for some reason.

```
<xcdg:DataGridControl x:Name="DictionariesDataGridControl" ItemsSource="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource DictionariesViewSource}}" AutoCreateColumns="False" AutoRemoveColumnsAndDetailConfigurations="False" SelectionMode="Extended" NavigationBehavior="RowOnly">
    <xcdg:DataGridControl.View>
        <xcdg:TableView UseDefaultHeadersFooters="False" ShowRowSelectorPane="False" VerticalGridLineThickness="0">
            <xcdg:TableView.FixedHeaders>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <xcdg:ColumnManagerRow BorderThickness="0"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </xcdg:TableView.FixedHeaders>
        </xcdg:TableView>
    </xcdg:DataGridControl.View>
    <xcdg:DataGridControl.Columns>
        <xcdg:Column FieldName="IsSelected" MinWidth="20" MaxWidth="20" CellEditorDisplayConditions="RowIsCurrent">
            <xcdg:Column.CellContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding ., Mode=OneWay}" IsHitTestVisible="False"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </xcdg:Column.CellContentTemplate>
            <xcdg:Column.CellEditor>
                <xcdg:CellEditor>
                    <xcdg:CellEditor.EditTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding ., Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </xcdg:CellEditor.EditTemplate>
                </xcdg:CellEditor>
            </xcdg:Column.CellEditor>
        </xcdg:Column>
    </xcdg:DataGridControl.Columns>
```

**EDIT 1**

I'm trying this, which does exactly what I need:

```
<xcdg:Column FieldName="IsSelected" MinWidth="20" MaxWidth="20" CellEditorDisplayConditions="Always"/>
```

*except* that, for some reason, the `CheckBox` is styled with a blue background!

[image: Check boxes with blue backgrounds]

I've selected the element in the visual tree that has a `Background` property defined as `SolidColorBrush` with `#FF0000FF` as the color:

[image: Visual tree]

**EDIT 2**

I decompiled the `DataGridCheckBox` class that Xceed uses to render the `CheckBox` and found this override:

```
public override void OnApplyTemplate()
{
  base.OnApplyTemplate();
  this.ChildCheckBox.Background = (Brush) new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
}
```

What a bizarre decision by Xceed to arbitrarily set the background color to blue.

**EDIT 3**

Using @JBrooks' answer, I tried the following:

```
<xcdg:Column FieldName="IsSelected" MinWidth="20" MaxWidth="20" CellEditorDisplayConditions="Always">
    <xcdg:Column.CellEditor>
        <xcdg:CellEditor>
            <xcdg:CellEditor.EditTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding ., Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </xcdg:CellEditor.EditTemplate>
        </xcdg:CellEditor>
    </xcdg:Column.CellEditor>
</xcdg:Column>
```

Unfortunately, for some reason the setter on the `IsSelected` property is never called when I check the box. The getter is called several times, though, and the `CheckBox`es are appearing correctly on initial bind.

Comment: This is apparently a known bug in `DataGridCheckBox`. So much for code review... http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/workitem/20210

Comment: By "this" I mean the blue background silliness.

Comment: 3 questions: Is there anything in the output window? Do you have something similar to the event CurrentCellChanged captured? Do the setter get set when the checkbox loses focus?

Comment: 1. Nothing in the Output window, no. I don't have any special logging turned on, though. 2. The only event I've explicitly wired to is `ItemsSourceChangeCompleted`, in order to populate the collection view's `SortDescriptions` collection. 3. The setter is never called no matter how I manipulate the check boxes, including changing selections, using `TAB` key, etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set up the datagrid control from the Xceed\Extended WPF Toolkit with checkbox column and binding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20203874/how-to-set-up-the-datagrid-control-from-the-xceed-extended-wpf-toolkit-with-chec)

Comment: I voted to close my question as a duplicate. It turns out the problem was simply changing it to `FieldName="."` and `{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}`.

Comment: `xcdg:Column.CellEditor` kills the setter for me as well and i cant get rid of the blue checkbox without it. did u figure something out? @NathanAldenSr

Comment: fixed in version 6.1.16565.14160, see https://xceed.com/release-notes/

Answer (score 1):

You have both a CellContentTemplate and a CellEditor, so the first click does the "go into edit mode" logic. Just have a single one like below. This is for a normal WPF DataGrid, but maybe you can try something similar for your grid.

```
  <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Active" SortMemberPath="IsActive"  >
     <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
           <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsActive, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled}" Style="{StaticResource rightsCB}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
  </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

For this DataGrid I also have these properties set:

`SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedUser, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}`" 
`SelectionUnit="FullRow"  SelectionMode="Single"`

So this DataGrid does act like what you want - I click the checkbox in row 4 and the IsChecked changes and it also makes row 4 the current row which sets the SelectedUser to the user bound to row 4.